# Compute geodesic circles on a Surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, geodesic

If I'm asked how to cumpute a geodesic circle on a parametrized surface $x:U\rightarrow S$ centered at a point $p \in S$ my approach would be to

$1$. Compute all the geodesics $\gamma_\theta(t)$ such that $\gamma_\theta(0) = p$ and $\gamma_\theta'(0) = \cos(\theta)x_u + \sin(\theta)x_v$ using the geodesic differential equations.

$2$. If I want $r$ to be the radius of the geodesic circle, setting $C(\theta) = \gamma_\theta(r)$ as the geodesic circle.

This process though feels like a lot of work, is there a simpler way of finding a geodesic circle centered at a point?

Comment: Is your $x$ geodesic polar coordinates?

Comment: @JohnMa nope, just a parametrization, finding geodesic polar coordinates at a point would require to compute all the geodesics passing through it wouldn't it? So it's the same problem I think.

Comment: If it is the polar coordinates, then the geodesic circle of radius $r$ is just $(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$. In general i don't think you can find the geodesic circle. After all you can't find an explicit formula for geodesic in general, even when the parametrization is explicit.

Comment: @JohnMa ok, what if I suppose that the first fundamental written with respect to $x$ is diagonal (on a cone for example)? Would that make it easier?